# Sum of square distances from a point to the sides of a regular polygon

Tags: geometry, triangles

> Let $A_1, A_2, A_3, ....... , A_n$ be vertices of a regular polygon of $n$ sides circumscribed about a circle whose centre is O and radius is $a$. P is any point other than O inside the circle. Then show that sum of squares from P to the sides of polygon is $n(a^2 + \dfrac{c^2}{2})$, where OP = c.

I just need to prove that $(a + c)^2 cos^2{\dfrac{\pi}{n}} = a^2 + \dfrac{c^2}{2}$. How shall I prove that

Comment: What is the *sum of squares*? Please detail.

Comment: You mean sum of square of the distances of $P$ to the sides of the polygon?

Comment: Consider square ABCD inscribed in circle with radius a. suppose p is between A and O, then Sum of squares will be $S=2a^2+2c^2=4(\frac{a^2}{2}+\frac{c^2}{2})$ . Is this an exception?

Comment: @sirous I get $4a^2+2c^2$.

Comment: $PB^2=PD^2=a^2+c^2$, so $S=2PB^2=2a^2+2c^2$.

Comment: @sirous If $P$ lies on $AO$ then $PB^2=(a-c/\sqrt2)^2+(a+c/\sqrt2)^2=2a^2+c^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT.

If $S$ is the sum of the squared distances from $P$ to the sides of the polygon, then:
$$
S=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(a-c\cdot\cos\left(\phi+{2\pi\over n}k\right)\right)^2=
na^2+c^2\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\cos^2\left(\phi+{2\pi\over n}k\right)
-2ac\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\cos\left(\phi+{2\pi\over n}k\right).
$$
But: 
$$\cos^2\alpha={1+\cos2\alpha\over2} 
\quad\text{and}\quad
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\cos\left(\phi+{2\pi\over n}k\right)=0.
$$

[image]

Comment: What is $\phi$ here?

Comment: @Zenix $\phi=\angle POM_1$, where $M_1$ is the midpoint of the first side.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $$
S=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(a.cos{\dfrac{\pi}{n}} + c\cdot\cos\left(\phi+{2\pi\over n}k\right)\right)^2=
n(a.cos{\dfrac{\pi}{n}})^2+c^2\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\cos^2\left(\phi+{2\pi\over n}k\right)
+2ac.cos{\dfrac{\pi}{n}}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\cos\left(\phi+{2\pi\over n}k\right)?
$$

Comment: @Zenix Your formula would give a different result. Just draw a sketch to understand why it works.

Comment: I added a figure to help understanding the formula.